# Add / Remove Class when scroll to an ID in the mid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a website in twitter bootstrap with top fixed navigation.
I have two navigations, one is on top and other one is in mid. Top one have a fixed position but requirements are when we scroll to mid and reached to mid navigation, add fixed class to mid navigation and remove fixed class from top Navigation.

Thanks for help in advance.
Murtaza

Comment: Hi there and welcome to StackOverflow. If you could provide some example code to help us replicate your situation/problem, that would be a big help in getting answers to your question. Providing JSFiddle(.net)'s are a handy option to show examples too, although not the easiest to do with frameworks like Bootstrap. Perhaps some screenshots of what's currently not working along with your existing HTML code would help. Enjoy the network!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the following.

Demo : http://jsbin.com/hifakesu/1/

**JS** :

```
$( window ).scroll(function() {
  var scrollVal = $( window ).scrollTop();
  if(scrollVal==100){
    $(".test").addClass("fixed");
  }
});
```

**HTML** :

```
<html>
<body>

  <div class="test"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS** :

```
.test{
  height:700px;
  float:left;
  width:250px;
  background:#CCC;
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$( window ).scroll(function() {
  if($( window ).scrollTop()==$("yourId").offset().top){
    $("yourId").addClass("fixed");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Maj, I tried it and its not working for me, I removed the class of top nav but am still looking for a solution for when I remove the class from top same time I want to add class to mid nav.`